# PDFJS: error on Text rendering for the PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, ember.js, pdf.js

Recently the PDF rendering get a messed up text layer where text gets duplicated with the grey colored overlay.
No idea about how to fix it as when i remove   `textLayerFactory: new pdfjsViewer.DefaultTextLayerFactory()` it works fine. but need this as if not is render as images which takes a lot of time for large documents

Im using pdfjsViewer.PDFPageView

my code as follows

```
 getPdf() {

    var pdfDocument;

    if ( this._state !== 'inDOM' ) return false;

    pdfjsLib.disableRange = true;
    pdfjsLib.disableStream = true;

    let self = this;
    pdfDocument = pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.src);
    pdfDocument.promise.then(function(pdf) {
      self.set( 'pdfDocument', pdf );
      self.set( 'maxNumPages',  pdf.numPages );
      self.set( 'prevBtnDisabled', true );
      self.set( 'documentRendered', true );

      self.setViewportWidth();
      self.renderPdf();
    });

    return pdfDocument;
  },

  renderPdf() {

    var pdf = this.pdfDocument,
        maxNumPages,
        pagePromise;

    if ( !pdf ) return false;

    maxNumPages  = this.maxNumPages;

    pagePromise = this.getAndRenderPage( pdf, 1 );

    Array.apply( null, new Array( maxNumPages - 1 ) ).forEach( ( value, index ) => {

      pagePromise = pagePromise.then( () => this.getAndRenderPage( pdf, index + 2 ) );
    } );
  },

  getAndRenderPage( pdf, index ) {

    return pdf.getPage( index ).then( page => this.renderPage( page, index ) );
  },


  renderPage( pdfPage, pageNum ) {

    var parentWidth       = this.$().parent().width(),
        pageViewportScale = ( parentWidth >= this.get( 'breakpoints.mobile' ) ) ? 1.5 : 1.3,
        viewport          = pdfPage.getViewport( { scale: parentWidth / pdfPage.getViewport( { scale: pageViewportScale } ).width } ),
        container         = this.$().find( '.pdf_viewer--container' )[ 0 ],
        pdfPageView;

    pdfPageView = new pdfjsViewer.PDFPageView( {
      container: container,
      id: pageNum,
      scale: viewport.scale,
      defaultViewport: viewport,
     textLayerFactory: new pdfjsViewer.DefaultTextLayerFactory()

    } );
    var pages = this.get('pages');
    // Associates the actual page with the view, and drawing it
     pages.push( pdfPageView );
    this.set( 'pages', pages );
    this.set( 'scale', viewport.scale );z

    pdfPageView.setPdfPage( pdfPage );

    return pdfPageView.draw();
  },
```

i have seen same kind of questioned asked and its for angular 
Im importing his image as for the reference in here to give a more explanation about the issue

[image]

Reported Issue 
[PDFJS: Text layer rendering twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770055/pdfjs-text-layer-rendering-twice)

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm facing the same issue, I tried the below solution but didn't work for me.

Comment: yes. below is my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the new PDFjs, the CSS file needs to be added seperately from the node_modules folder. therefore i added this as

```
  app.import( 'node_modules/pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.css' );
```

and you can add this as a html import as well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.css">
```

more information about the example from PDFjs
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/pageviewer.html

Comment: Adding this doesnt really work ... What can be the issue.

Comment: Yeah, didn't work for me as well.

Comment: most probably the css classes needed for pdfjs is not present correctly. 
try a HTML import and check whats happening with the file that you import. if you get the import correctly and still issue is there, then check are you importing it in multiple places like nodemodules, babel scripts etc.